# Modifying ClickOnce Output Folder Hierarchy

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, clickonce

I'm attempting to publish a ClickOnce Office Extension project (VS2010). By default the output folder of ClickOnce has a child folder (with each version of the binary files) named "Application Files." I need to change this to something without a space in the name, for example "AppFiles."

I haven't found any place in the docs where this is explained and the few answers I have found have said to use Mage to manually modify .VSTO file next to the bootstrap setup.exe. I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

What is the best way to go about changing this?

---

I have tried a few different things. Instead of using the built in Microsoft.Common.props, In a copy of   Microsoft.Common.targets I've modified the _DeploymentApplicationFolderName property inside the _CopyFilesToPublishFolder target to "Application_Files." Also in a copy of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets, I've modified the Value of the ApplicationFilesFolderName property set inside InitializePublishProperties to "Application_Files."

Even after doing that, when I publish I get the following error:

```
Error 121   Publish failed with the following error: Could not find a part of the path '<path to output directory>\app.publish\Application Files\ProjectStats_1_0_0_15'.
```

I'm guessing the problem is this is happening when the copy from the output dir to the publish dir happens but I don't know. Either way, the output directory hierarchy seems fine and the VSTO refers to the proper path in the hierarchy for the relevant dlls. It's just the publish process fails.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's no way to fix this and still use the Publish wizard in Visual Studio. After looking at the code for the Publish method in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Project.ClickOnceProvider.BuildManager class in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Project.dll assembly, the directory name "Application Files" is hard coded. There is no way to automatically fix this from what I can tell.